# Foreach loop incorrect

Tags: php

In this crawler, it searches and crawls all links for the bbc homepage.

When it finds BBC News links, it inserts them into a table. But for some reason when the script is run it doesn't insert them into the table like it should.

Any ideas?

```
               foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
"title"       => Titles($link), //dont know what Titles is, variable or string?
"description" => getMetas($link),
"keywords" => getKeywords($link), 
"link"        => $link
   );
  if (empty($output["description"])) {
  $output["description"] = getWord($link);
  }
 }
 foreach ($ouput as $value) {
 if (substr($value, 0, 26) == "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") {

  $data = '"' . implode('" , "', $value) . '"';
  $success = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO news_story (title, description , keywords, link)
  VALUES (" . $data . ")" );
  print_r($data);

}}
```

Comment: A lot of ideas... What does a `var_dump($output);` return? Just before the `foreach` loop. Does this variable contain what you expect?

Comment: at least post the output from `print_r($data);`

Comment: Please try with that typo corrected: `foreach ($ouput as $value) {` => `foreach ($output as $value) {`

Comment: And to prevent the above failing silently, read about [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Comment: @Pharaoh Eagle eyes.. Noah, please set the error reporting correctly so you can see where you have an undefined variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 3):

In your second foreach loop you specify $ouput instead of $output:

```
foreach ($ouput as $value) {
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($output as $value) {
```

Comment: Credits goes to Pharaoh? ;)

Comment: Ha, yeh he spotted it before me. Didnt see his post until i had submitted mine!